# Can't call btrfs send from another program

Tags: go, docker, btrfs

I'm having a problem calling the send command in btrfs. Here are the symptoms:

Calling it with sudo works:

```
sudo btrfs send /path/to/snapshot #works
```

Calling it without sudo fails:

```
btrfs send /path/to/snapshot
ERROR: failed to determine mount point for /path/to/snapshot
```

I'm trying to call this from another program and strangely it gives me a different error. Called from within the program (using exec in go-lang) it gives the following error:

```
ERROR: can't perform the search -Operation not permitted
ERROR: could not resolve root_id for /path/to/snapshot
```

I've tried it from within the program with and without sudo and it seems to have the same result. Notice this is being run inside of docker.

Comment: Does it help to run `docker` with the `--privileged` option?